# Change the reference style for subfloats: from 1a to 1(a)

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, subfloats

How to change the reference style to subfloats (package `subfloat`) in a figure from `<number><letter>` to `<number>(<letter>)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`subfloat` documentation](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfloat), section 4 "Change the label format":

```
\renewcommand*\thesubfloatfigure{\themainfigure(\alph{subfloatfigure})}
```

or

```
\renewcommand*\thesubfloattable{\themaintable(\alph{subfloattable})}
```